# How to add a post-install function with distribute?

Tags: python, distribute

I'm trying to build a source distribution package with [distribute](http://packages.python.org/distribute) which should include a post-install method being called after the install is finished.

I tried this [distutils solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250038/how-can-i-add-post-install-scripts-to-easy-install-setuptools-distutils) but that leads to the setup not being completely carried out (e.g. requirement installation is missing).

So what's the preferred way to have a post-install function in a distribute source distribution package?