# Post-install script with Python setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, software-distribution, setup.py, pypi

Is it possible to specify a post-install Python script file as part of the setuptools setup.py file so that a user can run the command:

```
python setup.py install
```

on a local project file archive, or

```
pip install <name>
```

for a PyPI project and the script will be run at the completion of the standard setuptools install?  I am looking to perform post-install tasks that can be coded in a single Python script file (e.g. deliver a custom post-install message to the user, pull additional data files from a different remote source repository).

I came across [this SO answer from several years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250038/how-can-i-add-post-install-scripts-to-easy-install-setuptools-distutils) that addresses the topic and it sounds as though the consensus at that time was that you need to create an install subcommand.  If that is still the case, would it be possible for someone to provide an example of how to do this so that it is not necessary for the user to enter a second command to run the script?

Comment: Many setup.py have a `setup.py test` command that you use after `setup.py install`.

Comment: I am hoping to automate the script run rather than requiring the user to enter a second command.  Any thoughts?

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806485/execute-a-python-script-post-install-using-distutils-setuptools

Comment: Are you sure you need a post-install script? I'm pretty sure delivering a custom message can be done without one, and pulling additional data files might be better done by making a setuptools distribution for those data files and listing it as a dependency.

Comment: If you do need this, [this blog post](http://www.niteoweb.com/blog/setuptools-run-custom-code-during-install) that I found by a quick google looks like it would be useful. (Also see [Extending and Reusing Setuptools](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#extending-and-reusing-setuptools) in the docs.)

Comment: @Simon Well, you're looking at a comment from 4 years ago about something that probably isn't what someone with this problem wants, so you can't really expect it to be monitored and kept up to date. If this were an answer, it would be worth the effort to find new resources to replace them, but it's not. If you need the outdated information, you can always use the Wayback Machine, or you can search for the equivalent section in the current docs.

Answer (score 117):

**Note:** The solution below only works when installing a source distribution zip or tarball, or installing in editable mode from a source tree. It will *not* work when installing from a binary wheel (`.whl`)

---

This solution is more transparent:

You will make a few additions to `setup.py` and there is no need for an extra file.

Also you need to consider two different post-installations; one for development/editable mode and the other one for install mode.

Add these two classes that includes **your post-install** script to `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.develop import develop
from setuptools.command.install import install


class PostDevelopCommand(develop):
    """Post-installation for development mode."""
    def run(self):
        develop.run(self)
        # PUT YOUR POST-INSTALL SCRIPT HERE or CALL A FUNCTION

class PostInstallCommand(install):
    """Post-installation for installation mode."""
    def run(self):
        install.run(self)
        # PUT YOUR POST-INSTALL SCRIPT HERE or CALL A FUNCTION
```

and insert `cmdclass` argument to `setup()` function in `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    ...

    cmdclass={
        'develop': PostDevelopCommand,
        'install': PostInstallCommand,
    },

    ...
)
```

You can even call shell commands during installation, like in this example which does pre-installation preparation:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.develop import develop
from setuptools.command.install import install
from subprocess import check_call


class PreDevelopCommand(develop):
    """Pre-installation for development mode."""
    def run(self):
        check_call("apt-get install this-package".split())
        develop.run(self)

class PreInstallCommand(install):
    """Pre-installation for installation mode."""
    def run(self):
        check_call("apt-get install this-package".split())
        install.run(self)


setup(
    ...
```

*P.S. there are no any pre-install entry points available on setuptools. Read [this discussion](https://web.archive.org/web/20161202071142/https://bugs.python.org/setuptools/issue41) if you are wondering why there is none.*

Comment: Looks cleaner than the others, but doesn't this execute the custom code *before* the actual `install` command?

Comment: @raphinesse I guess so, I don't remember entirely. But there was a workaround. I will make a complete test and update my answer. Thanks for the notification.

Comment: It's up to you: if you call `run` on the parent *first* then your command is a post-install, otherwise it's a pre-install. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @kynan Absolutely. I voted for your answer. The other answers do not work for me.

Comment: The question title is about post-install not pre-install. So it is confusing to have the answer be about pre-install. I tried this answer assuming it was actually an answer to the post-install question, and then gave up when it didn't work. Only 3 days later did I stumble on the detailed comments (thank you kynan for the clearest explanation) and realize that there was actually an answer for post-install. So I have submitted an edit request.

Comment: @personal_cloud "*there is no any pre-install entry points available on setuptools. Read [this discussion](https://bugs.python.org/setuptools/issue41) if you are wondering why there is none.*"

`install.run(self)` is just finishing the installation and not doing much.

Comment: @mertyildiran Actually, I did a simple test, and `install.run(self)` is doing all of the `data_files` movement.

Comment: using this solution it seems that `install_requires` dependencies are ignored

Comment: @ealfonso I'm sure it does not have any effect on `install_requires`. How did you reach that conclusion? In this arrangement actually, it executes post-install script before installing Python package dependencies. Maybe you are confusing this to that?

Comment: I can confirm that this approach will ignore the `install_requires`. Tested on python 2.7.x. The `atexit` approach below will work

Comment: This didn't work for me with `pip install -e .` for `Python 3.6`. The `atexit` method below works though.

Comment: This didn't work for me with `pip3`. The install script ran when publishing the package, but not when installing it.

Comment: link to discussion it's broken

Comment: @JuanAntonioOrozco I have updated the broken link using Wayback Machine. I don't know why it's broken at this very moment. Maybe something is wrong with https://bugs.python.org/ right now.

Comment: To @JoshuaH, this can be resolved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915469/python-setuptools-install-requires-is-ignored-when-overriding-cmdclass

Comment: Just seem to work with `setup.py install` and NOT when `pip install`ing the package.

Comment: @Raf is there a solution that works for both `setup.py install` and `pip install`?

Comment: How to extend this to also work for `.whl`? where is the failure point for such installations?

Comment: What's the status of this for the new `.toml` standard?

Answer (score 21):

**Note:** The solution below only works when installing a source distribution zip or tarball, or installing in editable mode from a source tree. It will *not* work when installing from a binary wheel (`.whl`)

---

This is the only strategy that has worked for me when the post-install script requires that the package dependencies have already been installed:

```
import atexit
from setuptools.command.install import install


def _post_install():
    print('POST INSTALL')


class new_install(install):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(new_install, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        atexit.register(_post_install)


setuptools.setup(
    cmdclass={'install': new_install},
```

Comment: Why do you register an `atexit` handler rather than simply calling the post install function after the installation step?

Comment: @kynan It's what worked for me. `setuptools` is very undocumented. See other (amended) answers in this Q&A in which people have finally figured out who to do it with only `setuptools`.

Comment: Why do you use `atexit` instead of just calling `_post_install()` in your `cmdclass`?

Comment: @kynan Because `setuptools` is quite under-documented. Others have already amended their answers on this Q&A with the correct solutions.

Comment: Well the other answers do not work for me: either the post install script is not executed, or the dependencies are not handled anymore. So far, I'll stick to `atexit` and **not** redefining `install.run()` (this is the reason why the dependencies are not handled anymore). In addition, in order to know the install directory, I've put `_post_install()` as a method of `new_install`, what lets me access to `self.install_purelib` and `self.install_platlib` (don't know which one to use, but `self.install_lib` is wrong, weirdly).

Comment: I was also having problems with dependencies and atexit works for me

Comment: None of the methods here seem to work with wheels. Wheels do not run setup.py so, the messages are only displayed when building, not when installing the package.

Comment: Thank you for providing this answer. It works for me (as does the answer provided by @mertyildiran ). One thing i found is that the output of the `print` statement is only shown if i run pip install in verbose mode, for example: `pip3 install -v -e .`

Comment: @sunyata Amazing, I didn't realize the installation went through but did not show up!

Comment: For me when atexit was called, files in setup's script argument were still not written to disk. However, after pip install finishes, the files are there

Answer (score 8):

**Note:** The solution below only works when installing a source distribution zip or tarball, or installing in editable mode from a source tree. It will *not* work when installing from a binary wheel (`.whl`)

---

A solution could be to include a `post_setup.py` in `setup.py`'s directory. `post_setup.py` will contain a function which does the post-install and `setup.py` will only import and launch it at the appropriate time.

In `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.command.install_data import install_data

try:
    from post_setup import main as post_install
except ImportError:
    post_install = lambda: None

class my_install(install_data):
    def run(self):
        install_data.run(self)
        post_install()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(
        ...
        cmdclass={'install_data': my_install},
        ...
    )
```

In `post_setup.py`:

```
def main():
    """Do here your post-install"""
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

With the common idea of launching `setup.py` from its directory, you will be able to import `post_setup.py` else it will launch an empty function.

In `post_setup.py`, the `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement allows you to manually launch post-install from command line.

Comment: In my case, overriding ``run()`` causes the package dependencies not to be installed.

Comment: @Apalala that was because the wrong `cmdclass` was replaced, I've fixed this.

Comment: Ah, finally, we find the right answer. How come wrong answers get so many votes on StackOverflow? Indeed, you have to run your `post_install()` *after* the `install_data.run(self)` otherwise you'll be missing some stuff. Like `data_files` at least. Thank you kynan.

Comment: Does not work for me. I guess, for any reason, the command `install_data` is not executed in my case. So, hasn't `atexit` the advantage of ensuring the post install script will be executed in the end, in any situation?

Answer (score 3):

Combining the answers from @Apalala, @Zulu and @mertyildiran; this worked for me in a Python 3.5 environment:

```
import atexit
import os
import sys
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install

class CustomInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        def _post_install():
            def find_module_path():
                for p in sys.path:
                    if os.path.isdir(p) and my_name in os.listdir(p):
                        return os.path.join(p, my_name)
            install_path = find_module_path()

            # Add your post install code here

        atexit.register(_post_install)
        install.run(self)

setup(
    cmdclass={'install': CustomInstall},
...
```

This also gives you access the to the installation path of the package in `install_path`, to do some shell work on.

Comment: What is `my_name` here?

Comment: `my_name` is the name of the installed package, and is the same name you parse to the `setup` function's `name` keyword parameter.

Comment: What if `my_name` lives inside `pyproject.toml` and not inside `setup.py`?

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer Then you could bootstrap the `setup.py` file itself from the `pyproject.toml` by making a script that extracts the package name from the toml file and then creates a `setup.py` file (possibly from a `setup.py.in` template file) with the package name embedded in it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to perform the post-install, and keep the requirements, is to decorate the call to `setup(...)`:

```
from setup tools import setup


def _post_install(setup):
    def _post_actions():
        do_things()
    _post_actions()
    return setup

setup = _post_install(
    setup(
        name='NAME',
        install_requires=['...
    )
)
```

This will run `setup()` when declaring `setup`. Once done with the requirements installation, it will run the `_post_install()` function, which will run the inner function `_post_actions()`.

Comment: Did you try this? I am trying with Python 3.4 and install works as normal but the post_actions are not executed...

Answer (score 1):

If using atexit, there is no need to create a new cmdclass. You can simply create your atexit register right before the setup() call. It does the same thing.

Also, if you need dependencies to be installed first, this does *not* work with pip install since your atexit handler will be called before pip moves the packages into place.

Comment: Like a few suggestions posted here, this one doesn't account for whether or not you are running in "install" mode or not.  That's the point of why custom "command" classes are employed.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to solve a problem with any presented recommendations, so here is what helped me.

You can call function, that you want to run after installation just after `setup()` in `setup.py`, like that:

```
from setuptools import setup

def _post_install():
    <your code>

setup(...)

_post_install()
```