# Compiling & installing C executable using python's setuptools/setup.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, setup.py

I've got a python module that calls an external binary, built from C source.

The source for that external executable is part of my python module, distributed as a .tar.gz file.

Is there a way of unzipping, then compiling that external executable, and installing it using setuptools/setup.py?

What I'd like to achieve is:

- installing that binary into virtual environments
- manage compilation/installation of the binary using `setup.py install`, `setup.py build` etc.
- making the binary part of my python module, so that it can be distributed as a wheel without external dependencies

Comment: Did you solve this problem? If so, can you share your solution? Thanks

Comment: I did in the end, I'll add an answer shortly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved in the end by modifying `setup.py` to add additional handlers for commands which did the installation.

An example of a `setup.py` which does this might be:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install
import subprocess

def get_virtualenv_path():
    """Used to work out path to install compiled binaries to."""
    if hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix'):
        return sys.prefix

    if hasattr(sys, 'base_prefix') and sys.base_prefix != sys.prefix:
        return sys.prefix

    if 'conda' in sys.prefix:
        return sys.prefix

    return None


def compile_and_install_software():
    """Used the subprocess module to compile/install the C software."""
    src_path = './some_c_package/'

    # compile the software
    cmd = "./configure CFLAGS='-03 -w -fPIC'"
    venv = get_virtualenv_path()
    if venv:
        cmd += ' --prefix=' + os.path.abspath(venv)
    subprocess.check_call(cmd, cwd=src_path, shell=True)

    # install the software (into the virtualenv bin dir if present)
    subprocess.check_call('make install', cwd=src_path, shell=True)


class CustomInstall(install):
    """Custom handler for the 'install' command."""
    def run(self):
        compile_and_install_software()
        super().run()


setup(name='foo',
      # ...other settings skipped...
      cmdclass={'install': CustomInstall})
```

Now when `python setup.py install` is called, the custom `CustomInstall` class is used, this then compiles and installs software before the normal install steps are run.

You can also do similar for any other steps you're interested in (e.g. build/develop/bdist_egg etc.).

An alternative is to make the `compile_and_install_software()` function a subclass of `setuptools.Command`, and create a fully fledged setuptools command for it.

This is more complicated, but lets you do things like specify it as a subcommand of another command (to e.g. avoid executing it twice), and to pass custom options in to it on the command line.