# What is the most conventional way to integrate C code into a Python library using distutils?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, setup.py, distutils

Many well-known python libraries are basically written in C (like tensorflow or numpy) because this apparently speeds things up a lot. I was able to very easily integrate a C function into python by reading [this](https://realpython.com/build-python-c-extension-module/).
Doing so I can finally use `distutils` to access the functions of the `source.c` file:

```py
# setup.py

from distutils.core import setup, Extension

def main():
    setup(
        # All the other parameters...
        ext_modules=[ Extension("source", ["source.c"]) ]
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

so that when i run `python setup.py install` i can install my library.
However, what if i want to create a python-coded wrapper object for the functions inside `source.c`? Is there a way to do this without polluting the installed modules? 
Wandering around the internet I have seen some seemingly simple solutions using shared libraries (`.so`). However I would need a solution that does not involve attaching the compiled C code, but one that compiles it the first time the program is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shared libraries are the right way to go in this case. The `distutils` have ability to build the static libraries as follows:

```py
from distutils.ccompiler import new_compiler
from distutils import sysconfig

c = new_compiler()
workdir = "."
c.add_include_dir( sysconfig.get_python_inc() )
c.add_include_dir("./include")
objects = c.compile(["file1.c", "file2.c"])
c.link_shared_lib(objects, "mylibrary", output_dir=workdir)
```

This will generate the `.so` library in the working directory.

For example how it's used in real `setup` see the [following example](https://github.com/SunPower/SolarUtils/blob/6ea5aca2e354dfec980201e84c7812a305c5eb25/setup.py)

Comment: hi thanks for answering my question. What are `c.add_include_dir("./include")` and `c.link_shared_lib(objects, "mylibrary", output_dir=workdir)` supposed to do? Also, i tried to execute your code, and it generates me two files, one `.so` and one `.o`, what's the difference?

Comment: The `.o` object is the intermediate binary object file that compiler generates. The `.so` is the shared library. For each `.c` file you will have a `.o` file generated, and than the files will be combined in a library. After the files are combined, you can remove the `.o`.

Comment: ok thanks, what about "c.add_include_dir("./include")"?

Comment: This one is if you have special header files of other files you want to include in the build. Think of this as an python version of a `Makefile`, so I added the line to help someone who has the need to include additional files.

Comment: is there a way to make the `.o` files be generated in a directory different from their `.c` files?

Comment: hi, i the compiling works just fine, but when i try to `#include <Python.h>` clang (that i suppose is the default compiler of distutils) raises `fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found`, what should i do?

Comment: You need to have python in the include. Also python development packages should be installed. If you still have issue, share the snipped of the code so I can check what you are doing.

Comment: the project is here https://github.com/Giuppox/block , the thing is not that complicated, i just use `setup.py` to compile `block/core.c` (where i try to `#include <Python.h>`)  inside a generated folder `block/build`. Sorry for the huge amount of questions, and thanks for your help!

Comment: @Giuppox I have send pull request with the fix. Check your repository

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229683/discussion-between-jordanvrtanoski-and-giuppox).

Comment: hi it is also possible to do something similar using setuptools? i was reading some articles and it seems like it is the standard now...

Comment: It looks like you can by calling shell commands. This is what I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168482/compiling-installing-c-executable-using-pythons-setuptools-setup-py), but I never used this before. If I was doing the attached example, I would have used `distutils` to compile instead of using shell commands.