# Packaged Python C Extension is missing PyInit_module() in so File

Tags: python, ctypes, setuptools, python-c-api

I have created a C library `libgac` and then wrote Python module implementing bindings with `ctype`.
I call the python module `gazepy`.

My project file structure is as follows:

```
pyproject.toml
setup.py
src
  gazepy
    gac          # repo with the C library libgac
    gazepy.py    # python bindings for the C library libgac
    __init__.py  # empty file
tests
```

Running `sudo pip install .` generates and installs the so file `gazepy.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

So far so good, however, if I want to import the library in a python3 shell I get the following error:

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_gazepy)
```

My `pyproject.toml` file:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "gazepy"
# ...
```

My `setup.py` file:

```py
from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages
import subprocess

module_name = "gazepy"
module_path = "src/" + module_name
gac_path = module_path + "/gac"
cglm_path = gac_path + "/cglm"

def main():
    setup(
            name=module_name,
            packages=find_packages(),
            ext_modules=[
                Extension(module_name, [gac_path + '/src/gac.c'],
                    include_dirs=[gac_path  + '/include', cglm_path + '/include'],
                    libraries=['m'])
            ]
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When looking at the so file `gazepy.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` I cannot find any definition of `PyInit_gazepy()`:

```bash
nm /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gazepy.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so | grep PyInit
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: StackOverflow/StackExchange is a QA (Questions-and-Answers) network. I suggest moving your solution to the answer box below even if you accept a different answer.

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to solve Python-C-API error "This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip."? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75307579/4788546)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python extension modules (`.so` and `.pyd` files) have higher priority than `.py` files when using the `import` command, so python is trying to import the `.so` file instead of the `.py` file.

in order for `import gazepy` to correctly import your python file you should change the name of the extension module `module_name` to have an underscore `_gazepy`, this way python is not going to load it, then you should only load your `.so` using ctypes.

---

you are compiling your C library as a python extension, which is wrong, as it now depends on python

the above solution will work although your library is not a python extension module, but you should consider [Compiling & installing C executable using python's setuptools/setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168482/compiling-installing-c-executable-using-pythons-setuptools-setup-py) so it won't depend on python, unfortunately this has worse portability than just treating this C library as an extension module, so if you care about producing a clean library you should try compiling it as a C library instead of an extension module, but if you care about low effort portability then keep your current python extension method.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Eventually, I ended up compiling and installing the C executable (as you recommended). I will add my final solution to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to my own question (based on Ahmeds reply)

I was not able to make the C extension work.
However, as pointed out by Ahmed it would anyways be better to compile the binary and add it to the package.

I ended up doing the following:

1. I changed my file structure as follows:

   ```
   pyproject.toml
   setup.py
   gac          # repo with the C library libgac
   gazepy
     gazepy.py    # python bindings for the C library libgac
     __init__.py  # empty file
     bin          # target location for so file
   tests
   ```
2. I used the following `setup.py` script (where I use my own Makefile and then copy the file to the `bin` folder):

   ```py
   from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages
   from setuptools.command.sdist import sdist
   import subprocess
   import os

   src_path = "gazepy"
   gac_path = "gac"

   def compile_and_install_software():
     """Used the subprocess module to compile/install the C software."""
     # compile the software
     subprocess.check_call('make', cwd=gac_path, shell=True)
     os.rename(gac_path + '/build/lib/libgac.so', src_path + '/bin/libgac.so')


   class CustomInstall(sdist):
     """Custom handler for the 'install' command."""
     def run(self):
       compile_and_install_software()
       super().run()


   def main():
     setup(
            name='gazepy',
            package_data={
                'gazepy':['bin/libgac.so']
            },
            packages=['gazepy', 'gazepy.bin'],
            cmdclass={'sdist': CustomInstall}
     )

   if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
   ```
3. Added the following line to the `__init__.py` file:

   ```py
   from .gazepy import *
   ```