# How to ship or distribute a matplotlib stylesheet

Tags: python, matplotlib, packaging

I want to distribute a custom [matplotlib style sheet](http://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html), but right now the only way I can think of is uploading it to Gist or some other website and tell my users to manually download it to some configuration directory.

Is there a way to distribute a style sheet as if it were a Python package, or as part of a module? Something easy like `pip install mpl_fancy`.

Comment: Please make this a github issue or ping the mpl-dev mailing list, we should provide an API to register styles and then you could have your package do that as a side-effect of being imported.  Currently you can reach into `mpl.style.core`, add a path to `USER_LIBRARY_PATHS` to point to your files and then re-run `mpl.style.core.reload_library()`.

Comment: You can also put in a PR adding your style to the mpl repo and we will ship it for you ;)

Comment: I just filed this issue: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4781 And for the PR... I might :)

Comment: just in case still useful  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36902139/815542) works for me

Answer (score 3):

After reading the link from @aloctavodia and consulting the [massmutual/mmviz-python GitHub repo](https://web.archive.org/web/20180613092546/https://github.com/massmutual/mmviz-python), this is what I came up with.

`setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install
import os
import shutil
import atexit

import matplotlib

def install_mplstyle():
    stylefile = "mystyle.mplstyle"

    mpl_stylelib_dir = os.path.join(matplotlib.get_configdir() ,"stylelib")
    if not os.path.exists(mpl_stylelib_dir):
        os.makedirs(mpl_stylelib_dir)

    print("Installing style into", mpl_stylelib_dir)
    shutil.copy(
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), stylefile),
        os.path.join(mpl_stylelib_dir, stylefile))

class PostInstallMoveFile(install):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        atexit.register(install_mplstyle)

setup(
    name='my-style',
    version='0.1.0',
    py_modules=['my_style'],
    install_requires=[
        'matplotlib',
    ],
    cmdclass={
        'install': PostInstallMoveFile,
    }
)
```

Into `my_style.py` I just put a basic example script. Now, my users can install this style with `pip install git+https://github.com/me/my-style`!

Comment: https://github.com/massmutual/mmviz-python no longer exists. I asked about it at https://github.com/massmutual/mmviz-python-examples/issues/3.

Comment: I've edited my question to use an Internet Archive link.