# How can I share matplotlib style?

Tags: python, matplotlib

One can load a custom plotting style in `matplotlib` with something like:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

And I know that I can create my own, http://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html explains how.

Let's say that I create an amazing matplotlib style -- how can I share this with other people? Is there a way to do it with pip/conda or something else appropriate?

The docs include the suggestion to "create custom styles and use them by calling style.use with the path or URL to the style sheet." -- so I guess that I could maintain a link w/ that on some public git repository, and people would just get the most recent style if they put that URL?

Answer (score 7):

You could organize your code in a structure like this:

```
|
└─── setup.py
└─── mplstyles
         style_01.mplstyle
         style_02.mplstyle
```

Then, in your file `setup.py` write something like the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib as mpl
import glob
import os.path
import shutil
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-install', action='store_true', default=True)
parser.add_argument('-upgrade', action='store_true')
options = parser.parse_args()

#~ # ref  ->  matplotlib/style/core
BASE_LIBRARY_PATH = os.path.join(mpl.get_data_path(), 'stylelib')
STYLE_PATH = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'mplstyles')
STYLE_EXTENSION = 'mplstyle'
style_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(STYLE_PATH,"*.%s"%(STYLE_EXTENSION)))

for _path_file in style_files:
    _, fname = os.path.split(_path_file)
    dest = os.path.join(BASE_LIBRARY_PATH, fname)
    if not os.path.isfile(dest) and options.install:
        shutil.copy(_path_file, dest)
        print("%s style installed"%(fname))
    elif options.upgrade:
        shutil.copy(_path_file, dest)
        print("%s style upgraded"%(fname))
    elif os.path.isfile(dest):
        print("%s style already exists (use -upgrade to upgrade)"%(fname))
    else:
        pass # ¿?
```

The code above copy each .mplstyle (or stylesheet) file from "mplstyles" folder  to Matplotlib installation directory.

#### "Install" styles

```
>> python setup.py -install
```

#### "Upgrade" styles

```
>> python setup.py -upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had this exact same question. A petty that was not been solved yet. I have found a solution to be able to distribute the style(s) using PyPi (in my case [goosempl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/goosempl/0.1.0), also on [GitHub](https://github.com/tdegeus/GooseMPL)).

I have created a Python module of which the `mplstyle`-files are a part:

```
|-- setup.py
|-- package_name
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- styles
|   |   |-- example.mplstyle
```

The idea is now:

1. The `.mplstyle` file(s) gets packaged with the module.
2. The module gets installed.
3. At the end of the installation a small script runs that extracts the `.mplstyle` file(s) from the newly installed package and writes them to the matplotlib config directory.

Here are the essentials

### setup.py

```
import atexit
from setuptools                 import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install

def _post_install():
    import goosempl
    package_name.copy_style()

class new_install(install):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(new_install, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        atexit.register(_post_install)

__version__ = '0.1.0'

setup(
    name              = 'package_name',
    version           = __version__,
    ...
    install_requires  = ['matplotlib>=2.0.0'],
    packages          = ['package_name'],
    cmdclass          = {'install': new_install},
    package_data      = {'package_name/styles':[
        'package_name/styles/example.mplstyle',
    ]},
)
```

### **init**.py

```
def copy_style():

  import os
  import matplotlib

  from pkg_resources import resource_string

  files = [
    'styles/example.mplstyle',
  ]

  for fname in files:
    path = os.path.join(matplotlib.get_configdir(),fname)
    text = resource_string(__name__,fname).decode()
    open(path,'w').write(text)
```

For future reference see these related questions / documentation:

- [Why use `package_data` and not `data_files`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43800753/pip-tries-to-install-package-in-the-wrong-location)
- [Running a post-installation script/command that relies on the installed package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288711/post-install-script-with-python-setuptools)
- [Uploading to PyPi](https://packaging.python.org/distributing/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi)