# pip tries to install package in the wrong location

Tags: python, pip

I have just created a Python package and uploaded it to PyPi ([goosempl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/goosempl/0.1.0)). Installing the package locally works:

```
$ python3 setup.py install
```

(It installs in `usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`).

However installing it from PyPi gives a weird error:

```
$ pip3 install goosempl

...
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/goosempl'
```

For some reason pip tries to install in the wrong location?!?

---

Here is the `setup.py` (stripped down a bit, it still causes the error):

```
import atexit
from setuptools import setup

__version__ = '0.1.0'

setup(
    name              = 'goosempl',
    version           = __version__,
    author            = 'Tom de Geus',
    author_email      = 'tom@geus.me',
    url               = 'https://github.com/tdegeus/GooseMPL',
    keywords          = 'matplotlib style',
    description       = 'Style and extension functions for matplotlib',
    long_description  = '',
    license           = 'MIT',
    install_requires  = ['matplotlib>=2.0.0'],
    packages          = ['goosempl'],
    data_files        = [('goosempl/stylelib',[
        'goosempl/stylelib/goose.mplstyle'
    ])],
)
```

I have uploaded it to PyPi using:

```
$ python3 setup.py sdist
$ python3 setup.py bdist_wheel --universal
$ twine upload dist/*
```

(My guess in that the problem is caused by the `data_files`)

Comment: are you inside a virtualenv?

Comment: @NilsWerner No I'm not. (Furthermore, I'm using the homebrew Python on Mac)

Comment: It may be that `data_files` is the culprit, (`goosempl/stylelib` doesn't get expanded to `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/goosempl/stylelib` but `/usr/lib/goosempl/stylelib`). Try removing the lines and instead create a `MANIFEST.in` file containing just the line `goosempl/stylelib/goose.mplstyle`.

Comment: Also, did you really mean `python3 install setup.py`, or rather `python3 setup.py install`?

Comment: @NilsWerner With your directions I have solved it by changing `data_files` with `package_data` (with a slightly different syntax). But maybe you are better equipped to explain this difference, and the relation to `MANIFEST.in`?

Comment: `package_data` and `MANIFEST.in` are the same thing. They tell `setup.py sdist` what files besides `*.py` to include in the zip file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @NilsWerner:

The problem was in `data_files`. I have changed this with `package_data` (which has a slightly different syntax):

```
package_data = {'goosempl/stylelib':[
    'goosempl/stylelib/goose.mplstyle'
]},
```

This results in the desired behavior.

Following the comments, one could also include these files in `MANIFEST.in`.