# Post-install setup.py doesn't work

Tags: python, installation, setuptools

I'm trying to add a post-install step into the *setup.py*. The installation works but the code inside *run(self)* is never executed.

Things I've tried (with no result):

- Install it using both "*pip install (-e) .*" and "*python setup.py (develop)*" [and later uninstall it, reinstall it, delete .egg-info folder,...]
- Variations using: do_egg_install, build, bdist_egg,...

Versions:

- pip 8.1.2 (for Python 3.5)
- setuptools-20.2.2

Toy example:

```py
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install


class MyCommand(install):
    def run(self):
        print("Hello, developer, how are you? :)")
        install.run(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(
        cmdclass={
            'install': MyCommand,
        }
    )
```

Comment: How do you run your code? I ran your code with `python setup.py install` and it prints `Hello, developer, how are you? :)`. BTW: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288711/post-install-script-with-python-setuptools) is thread regarding post-installation script in `setup.py`.