# python setup.py - how to show message after install

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py

I am developing a PyQt5 app and making it available via `pip install` now that pip in python3 can install pyqt5 as dependence. I made an entry point to launch my package, and told setup.py that it's a gui_scripts.

What I would like to do now, is after the person typing `pip install package`, and the installation is finished, display a message to the person telling that you can now type `package` in the terminal to load the application. What's the correct way of doing that? Or should I not do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20288711/1005215

Answer (score 6):

If you can ensure that

- the package is always installed from a source distribution, not a binary wheel, and
- the user uses the `-v` option for `pip install`,

you can output text in your `setup.py` script.

The `setup.py` is almost a regular Python script.
Just use the `print()` function at the end of your `setup.py` file.
In this example the file structure is `somedir/setup.py`, `somedir/test/` and `test/__init__.py`.

#### Simple solution

```
from setuptools import setup

print("Started!")

setup(name='testing',
      version='0.1',
      description='The simplest setup in the world',
      classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.0',
      ],
      keywords='setup',
      author='someone',
      author_email='someone@example.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['test'],
      entry_points={
      },
      zip_safe=False)

print("Finished!")
```

> Started! 
> running install 
> running bdist_egg 
> running egg_info
>  writing testing.egg-info/PKG-INFO 
>   ...
>  ...
>  ...
>   Processing dependencies for testing==0.1 
> Finished processing
>   dependencies for testing==0.1 
> Finished!

#### Using `setuptools.command.install` solution

Also, you can subclass the `setuptools.command.install` command. Check the difference when you change the order of `install.run(self)` and `os.system("cat testing.egg-info/PKG-INFO")` in a clean setup.

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install
import os


class PostInstallCommand(install):
    """Post-installation for installation mode."""
    def run(self):
        install.run(self)
        os.system("cat testing.egg-info/PKG-INFO")


setup(name='testing',
      version='0.1',
      description='The simplest setup in the world',
      classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.0',
      ],
      keywords='setup',
      author='someone',
      author_email='someone@example.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['test'],
      entry_points={
      },
      cmdclass={
        'install': PostInstallCommand,
      },
      zip_safe=False)
```

Comment: Annoyingly enough, *pip* gobbles up these custom messages unless you run it with *-v* or such. The tasks work, but you just don't see the messages.

Comment: Also I have not found a way to make this work with pip-installing wheeels. They do not "run" `setup.py` at installation - only when packaging into a `.whl`.

Answer (score -3):

Another option would be the logging module.

[rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/setup.py) for example uses an approach like this which you could adapt for your needs:

```
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger()

...

log.info("Your message")
```

`sys.stderr` will be printed by pip.