# setup.py post-install scripts and pip install extras

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, post-install

I'm developing a package which has a few optional dependencies and 'extras'.

**Goal:**
I want the following two things to work:

1. Execute my post-install code
2. Allow for 'extras' installation

**Status:** Currently I have been able to:

1. Use `python setup.py install` or `python setup.py develop` to execute post-install code; using the method here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36902139/8473819
2. Use `pip install PACKAGE[extra]` to properly install/manage extras or different package configurations.

In my research I have not found a feature of `python setup.py` to allow 'extras' nor a `pip install` feature to allow my post-install code to execute. *changed, see update

**Notes:**

Using pip 9.0.1, python 3.6

My post-install is simple, it just gets some information about available resources, creates a file, and prints some feedback using `print()`.

**Question:** Have I missed some features, or is there not a way to *cleanly* accomplish both actions with just one of the install methods?

**Update:**

The `pip install` method does in fact execute my post-install code (prints are piped somewhere, only visible using `-vvv` arg). Another problem is that (unless installed with `-e`) it uses a temporary build directory like `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ix4d6hv3-build` then cleans it up, instead of building in the local directory. In this case, the my file creation either does not work, I have been unable to locate where the file is created, or it is cleaned up by pip (I tried `--no-clean` with same results).

**Reference for others:**

If installing from a local directory (not a tar/whl/etc. file), the package will be copied to a temporary directory see ^update^. Then a `setuptools.command.egg_info` subclass in `setup.py` will be executed before `setuptools.command.install` or `setuptools.command.develop` *(passed in `cmdclass` arg)*.

Comment: 1. There's no way to detect `extras` in `setup.py` because they are not passed to it - the extras are parsed and handled by `pip`/`easy_install` and are not passed any further. 2. The `install` command is not executed by `pip`, so you post-install code will not be executed either. In fact, `pip` does not use or ship the `setup.py` at all, since there is no place for it in the wheel format specification.

Comment: Pip still uses setup() inside setup.py though, to obtain package information. So does pip ignore the 'cmdclass'  argument entirely or just the 'install'/'develop' where post-install functions are placed?  Note My package is not on pypi, I pip install from local.