# setuptools: is it possible to install different file or files depending on devel or install?

Tags: python, setuptools

I am trying to make a system-wide installation of my Python module with setuptools.

Let's say I have a file that has to have different content depending on whether I install in production or development environment.

One way I think I found, is from [Post-install script with Python setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288711/post-install-script-with-python-setuptools) . As far as I understand, I could make some additional post-install actions and in them copy the correct version of the file depending on whether it is devel or install, however, how do I know from within the method, which directories to use for source and dest?

Comment: Boo, don't do this the people using your paackages will curse you - potentially. Maybe use extras_require instead?

Answer (score 1):

> how do I know from within the method, which directories to use for source and dest?

This is not really well documented. You will have to read some of `distutils` and `setuptools` code. I believe the destination for the `develop` should be `self.install_dir` and `self.install_lib` for the `install` command. For the source, I believe it should be good enough to assume a path relative to the location of your `setup.py` script.

Something like this (untested):

```
class develop(setuptools.command.develop.develop):
    def run(self):
        super().run(self)
        self.copy_file('src/package/develop.bin', self.install_dir + 'package/data.bin')

class install(setuptools.command.install.install):
    def run(self):
        super().run(self)
        self.copy_file('src/package/install.bin', self.install_lib + 'package/data.bin')
```