# Python: Best way to integrate a functionality test into a package for end user

Tags: python, automated-tests

I wrote a Python3 package which I am soon going to ship/share via PyPI and Github.

Now I am looking for the optimal solution for the end user to have a small test which can be run to see if after `setup.py build` and `setup.py install` the package/analysis works on the end users' system. I am NOT talking about a test on the development side.

I would ship some toy data set in order to perform the test since my package is used for data analysis.

My thoughts on this:

1. `setup.py test` would be a nice option but it seems to be deprecated soon
2. I do not want a solution where the end user has to install an additional package like `pytest` or `tox` first

Any recommendations on how to integrate a test into my package considering the two points above?

Comment: You might be interested in this question about [post-install script with Python setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20288711/3767239) as well.

Comment: There is a software quality and assurance SE https://sqa.stackexchange.com/ you may find this type of question is a better place for.

Comment: @possum Thanks for pointing this out. Was not aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a [`__main__.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) file which contains the test logic. Then the user can invoke the test via `python -m your-package-name test` if they wish to. For example:

```py
# __main__.py

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('mode', choices=('test',))

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.mode == 'test':
    # perform test logic here
    ...
```

Alternatively you can specify a command line script as an entry point in `setup.py` which allows your users to invoke `your-pkg-name-test` from the command line. [This tutorial](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html) contains extensive information on how to realize this. Basically you need to add the following to your `setup.py`:

```py
setup(
    ...
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': ['my-pkg-test=mypkg.user_test:main'],
    }
    ...
)
```

and then ship an additional file `user_test.py` with the following function:

```py
def main():
    # test logic goes here
    ...
```

So the overall directory structure is as follows:

```
my-pkg/
├── mypkg
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py  # You can use either this ...
│   └── user_test.py  # ... or this together with 'console_scripts'.
└── setup.py
```

Comment: Thanks! In the end I wrote a testing script which calls main() with some parameters. It goes along the lines of your solution but did not integrate it into setup.py. Might do this later though...

Comment: @Michael It's important to note that `setup.py` is not invoked when *installing* from a wheel (`.whl`). It is however invoked when *building* that wheel. So if you intend to distribute your package as a wheel (which is useful) then including the tests in `setup.py` will not invoke them on the user site upon installation. This needs to be done separately by the user.