# Use SQL VIEWS in Django

Tags: django, django-views, sql-view

Is there any way to use the SQL Command  `CREATE VIEW` in Django?
If I Try To use regular syntax, or use

```
from django.db import connection
... 
with connection.cursor()
...
```

I get the Error:

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VIEW'.

Comment: What error did you get

Comment: Edited the Error

Comment: Post the SQL query that you are using. Also check if using a migration is suitable for your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66853070/how-to-programatically-create-a-database-view-in-django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as usual creating view in sql is look like below:

create view in SQL named **Test**:

```
from django.db import connection
...
...
def createView(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.Test')
        cursor.execute("CREATE VIEW Test AS \
                        SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...\
                        FROM some_table_name \
                        WHERE condition")
```

Check your syntax with mine, if still has problem please place your whole code here.