# Artifactory: Download and unzip zip file using pip install

Tags: python, artifactory

I created a repository, on Artifactory, which includes a zip containing 2 folders.
https://artifactory.healthcareit.net:443/artifactory/pi-generic-local/paymentintegrity-airflow-lib-plugins/paymentintegrity-airflow-libs-plugins-202211031330.zip

Is there a way to download that zip and extract the directories during a pip install?  Basically, the developer just runs a pip install and gets the directories where needed.

I'm not looking for something in the [scripts] section since installing these directories would be the only thing currently needed in the Pipfile (its a weird project).  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can abuse the install command in the `setup.py` to call any arbitrary code, such as a one that unzips the assets and install it at the right place.  I have seen this being done to package c++ binaries using python pypi in a place I worked for.  See [Post-install script with Python setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288711/post-install-script-with-python-setuptools) for hints on how to override the install command.

Answer (score 0):

As per my observations, you have created generic repo and trying to fetch the packages using pip install. I would recommend creating a [PyPI repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/PyPI+Repositories) in the Artifactory and then try fetching the packages. This will. help in creating the metadata which will maintain all the package versions in the repository.

If you have the packages in your local then [push them in the PyPI local repo](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-how-to-deploy-a-pypi-package-to-the-artifactorys-local-repository/) and when you resolve them from Artifactory it will automatically download for the pip install based on your requirement.

If your requirement is to zip up multiple packages and push the archive file to the Artifactory and want the Artifactory to unzip and give the dependeciense during the pip install - then this is not possible from the Artifactory side we need to use a Post-install script with Python setup tools as mentioned .