# Python Setuptools: Is it possible to add preinstall code which creates dynamic file?

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, setup.py

I have the following structure of packages:

```
repo  
|__pckg1
    |__settings.txt
    |__create_new_file.py
    |__setup.py
    |__requirements1.txt
|__pckg2
    |__requirements2.txt
```

Requirements2.txt has: file:../pckg1

create_new_file.py creates new file based on settings.txt
It should run before setup.py so the newly created file will be part of the installation.
Is it possible to achieve this?

I tried all the options from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288711/post-install-script-with-python-setuptools) but nothing worked

Comment: There is `PostInstallCommand` in an answer of the linked question. You can make it `PreInstallCommand` and call you code before calling `install.run(self)`. The warning remains though: "*Note: The solution below only works when installing a **source distribution** zip or tarball, or installing in editable mode from a source tree. **It will not work when installing from a binary wheel (.whl)***" — emphasize mine.

Comment: Thank you @phd, there is another issue with this approach - in order to run 'create_new_file.py' needs it's dependencies to be installed..