# How to clone and compile C++ code into binaries within the package during `pip install`?

Tags: c++, pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I need to make a Python package [openface](https://github.com/GuillaumeRochette/openface), that will act as an API of some existing C++ research code [OpenFace](https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace), that I don't own.

I have forked the existing code base into [openface-backend](https://github.com/GuillaumeRochette/openface-backend), and rewrote the installation script `install.sh` to not require `sudo`, such that after cloning the repository and installing the system requirements, it compiles the code and download assets `build/bin`.
At that point, one can run `./bin/foo --bar /path/to/abc --baz /path/to/xyz` and it all works.

Regarding the Python package, for a starter it will be very basic.
For the executable `./bin/foo`, I will have a corresponding function `foo()`:

```py
import subprocess
import shlex

BINARY_PATH = "/path/to/bin/foo"

def foo(bar: str, baz: str):
    args = f"{BINARY_PATH} --bar {bar} --baz {baz}"
    try:
        process = subprocess.run(
            args=shlex.split(args),
            check=True,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
            text=True,
        )
        print(process.stdout)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as error:
        print(error.stdout)
```

I would like that when installing the package with `pip`, such as `pip install 'git+https://github.com/GuillaumeRochette/openface.git'`, the `openface-backend` repository would be downloaded and compiled, and that the binaries are to be moved somewhere in the package.

To try and make it work, I have followed the instructions from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288711/post-install-script-with-python-setuptools).

This is my `setup.py`:

```py
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.develop import develop
from setuptools.command.install import install

import subprocess
import shlex


def compile():
    args = (
        'bash -c "'
        "git clone https://github.com/GuillaumeRochette/openface-backend.git"
        " && "
        "cd openface-backend"
        " && "
        "bash install.sh"
        " && "
        "mv build/bin .."
        " && "
        "cd .."
        " && "
        "rm -rf openface-backend"
        '"'
    )
    try:
        process = subprocess.run(
            args=shlex.split(args),
            check=True,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
            text=True,
        )
        print(process.stdout)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(e.stdout)


class CustomDevelop(develop):
    def run(self):
        develop.run(self)
        compile()


class CustomInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        install.run(self)
        compile()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(
        cmdclass={
            "develop": CustomDevelop,
            "install": CustomInstall,
        },
    )
```

While the code is getting downloaded and compiled when doing `python setup.py install` within that repository, this is not happening when doing `pip install 'git+https://github.com/GuillaumeRochette/openface.git'`.
I don't know if it is the `pyproject.toml` which is missing something, or if my `setup.py` needs some changes or if this is something totally different.

Comment: As far as I know, by default *pip* does not run the `python setup.py install` command (nor `python setup.py develop`). -- Generally the advice you followed seems to be very outdated. I would not use this technique at all. I would need to take some more time to try to understand what you are trying to achieve to be able to give better, more up-to-date advice. -- This is quite a big undertaking anyway, you will need to do a lot of research invest quite a lot of time. -- I encourage you to ask here to get some advice on how to get started properly: https://discuss.python.org/c/packaging/14

Comment: Maybe you should look for other cases of Python bindings for a C++ library, if possible one that is state of the art, and try to get inspired from them. -- If you are into this kind of communication system, there is a Discord server for _PyPA_ which is the org dedicated to Python packaging: https://discuss.python.org/t/theres-a-pypa-discord-now/8515 and you might be able to get help there to get you started.