# An elegant means of installing APT packages within a Python Setuptools framework

Tags: python, setuptools, apt

I have created a **custom PIP package**, with the assistance of **Setuptools**. At one point in the code, my package does something like this:

```py
subprocess.run(["srm", path_to_file], check=True)
```

The difficulty with this is that, while I can assume a Linux OS in my case, `srm` is not a built-in command. You will need to run something like `sudo apt install install-delete` at least once. Therefore, I would like that install command to run whenever I call `pip install my_package`.

This is easy in principle but difficult in practise. [This question with its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288711/post-install-script-with-python-setuptools) lays out how to run any script as part of a Setuptools installation. In practise, this is not a viable strategy for running `sudo` commands because:

1. There is no way to communicate with the user via print statements within the Setuptools installation process.
2. As a result of (1), the user just gets a password prompt - without any context or explanation.

A few potential solutions:

- Force the Setuptools install process to display print statements - but how to do this?
- Add a `my-package-install-specials` script to the package - but how to communicate to the user that running this script is part of the installation process?
- Check that `secure-delete` is installed every time I invoke `srm` - but is this not bad practise?

Comment: State the required prerequisite packages in the documentation. Please don't ever try to do `sudo` things in a Python package installation script.

Comment: @Woodford Is there no way to add something like `print("By the way, run this script to complete the installation.)"` such that it will actually show up in the terminal? I feel like that would solve a ton of issues, but I can't find a way to do it.