# Is it possible to set SUID of console_script created by Python setuptools?

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, system-administration

I have certain scripts that are installed as console_scripts using Python's setuptools. This script is run as www-data user. But the script also needs access to SSL certs that can be read only by root user.

One of the possible solutions that I see to solving this problem is setting SUID on the generated console_script. I can do that manually using a Makefile, but I was looking for more of an out-of-the-box solution that is already provided by any packaging tool in the Python ecosystem.

Is this is possible at all? Or setting SUID using a Makefile is the best option I have?

Answer (score 1):

A better option may be to write the wrapper script yourself, have the appropriate SUID and GUID bits set before packaging, and then distribute it via the `scripts` setting rather than the `console_scripts` entry points. This saves you the problem of having to rely on `make` at the expense of a little extra project maintenance.

Another option would be to have a post-install hook which runs `os.chmod()` or `os.fchmod()` on the installed console script, but keep in mind that this will not work with .egg binary distributions (or possibly Python 3 .wheel.) [This SO answer has details on that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250038/how-can-i-add-post-install-scripts-to-easy-install-setuptools-distutils) Note that this means that the installer would have to be run as root, regardless of where the package is actually installed to (including a local environment.)