# Perform a command after pip install <package>

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, sdist

I bundle my package as a sdist zip file , after that i can import my package anywhere using pip install  , but i want to run some post install commands automatically after calling pip install.
I cannot use python setup.py install because it is a sdist and i am using pip to install it . I do have a PostInstall class but nothing runs after pip install package. Is there a way to automatically run a script after pip install package.
I have tried using postinstall but it doesnt work and also i am not sure how to use the scripts atrib in the setup method.

This is my setup.py file :
[Setup.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REwnQ.jpg)

I cannot use python setup.py install because it is a sdist and i am using pip to install it . I do have a MyInstall class but nothing run after pip install package.

Comment: I tried to follow this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288711/post-install-script-with-python-setuptools
where the same approach is used using setup.tools

Comment: if post-install scripts are not supported in wheel are there any other alternatives ?

Comment: Call the post-install script manually. Or use a native package format (deb, rpm) instead of sdist.

Comment: Well, in sdist you can implement post-install by running code after `install.run(self)`. But not in a wheel.

Comment: adding stuff after install.run(self) is not called either

Comment: if i do python setup.py install , it gets called but using pip install no

Comment: Strange. For an sdist `pip install` runs `python setup.py install`. What code did you try? Was it `print`?

Comment: what i meant was the the post-install script is being called if i use python setup.py install lets say for a bdist, but after that when i package it as a sdist and try to install using pip , it does not work , im not trying a print statement , i try to create a directory structure at the install location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post install script after installing a wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263774/post-install-script-after-installing-a-wheel)

Comment: @phd yep thats right, however for wheel i was able to pass a script in the setup.py scripts option, which is passed where ever i pip install the proj and can be executed manually.