# How can I specify a post-uninstall script for a Python package with setuptools / pip?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, win32com

I'm creating a Python package that registers a COM server after install using the approach described in [Post-install script with Python setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288711/post-install-script-with-python-setuptools). How can specify a post-uninstall (or pre-uninstall) script to unregister the COM server when the package is uninstalled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: execute action at package uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50088440/python-execute-action-at-package-uninstall)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+pre-uninstall

Comment: Short answer — you cannot.

Comment: You might be able to do that with PyInstaller or something equivalent