# Post installation script in setuptools with sudo privileges

Tags: python, setuptools, systemd

I'm trying to build a `setup.py` file to install a python script as a service. So far, I can install the script and manually add a unit in systemd and enable/launch the service, but I'd like to do it automatically. The problem I have is that my bash script which build the unit file requires sudo privileges and I dont want to run `pip install` with `sudo`.

```
import os
import subprocess
from setuptools import setup, Extension
import setuptools.command.install
from distutils.command.build import build as build_orig


class install(setuptools.command.install.install):
    def run(self):
        setuptools.command.install.install.run(self)
        current_dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        create_service_script_path = os.path.join(current_dir_path, 'bin', 'create_service.sh')
        subprocess.check_output([create_service_script_path])


setup(name='dspt',
      version=dspt.__version__,
      packages=['dspt'],
      include_package_data=True,
      package_data={"": ["data/template.xml"]},
      ext_modules=[ext],
      install_requires=['slackclient==1.3.1',
                        'numpy',
                        'numba',
                        'scipy',
                        'pytz',
                        'requests',
                        'pyjwt',
                        'pysmb',
                        'boto3'],
      cmdclass={
          'install': install
      },
      entry_points={'console_scripts': ['run_dspt = dspt.batch_processing:main']}
)
```

**create_service.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
SYSTEMD_SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd  $(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE:=$0}") && pwd)
cp -f "$SYSTEMD_SCRIPT_DIR/dspt.service" /etc/systemd/system
chown root:root /etc/systemd/system/dspt.service

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable dspt.service
```

**unit file**

```
[Unit]
Description=My super service
After=multi-user.target network.target

[Service]
User=myuser
Group=mygroup
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
Type=idle
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
ExecStart=/home/myuser/miniconda3/envs/dspt/bin/run_dspt

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note that for now, the unit file supposes that the package is installed in a conda virtual environment named `dspt`.

The bash script `create_service.sh` obvioulsy requires sudo privileges and I cant figure how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post install script after installing a wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263774/post-install-script-after-installing-a-wheel)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+post-install+script

Comment: havent seen the first post...