# Is it possible to include python command as part of requirements.txt or other project file?

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, requirements.txt

I have some python command for installing a specific wheel that would otherwise not be installed by just running pip directly on a requirements.txt file. Is there a way to incorporate this command as part of this or another file to be run on startup?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58312692/create-a-python-script-that-install-python-modules-and-run-some-commands.

Comment: If i make some .sh file I would have to run the file through my bash.exe interpreter, vs python I assume?

Comment: You can run a bash script from python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745648/running-bash-script-from-within-python

Comment: Does subprocess work with bash commands as well? (not just scripts)

Comment: Yes. You can check: `subprocess.run('ls')` or `subprocess.call('ls')` will enlist all the folder contents in your current folder.

Comment: okay perfect thanks